# create a button from class constructor

Tags: java, android

I would like programmatically to create a button from a new class constructor. It is not the main class.

```
class myChips
{
    ImageView slika;
    RelativeLayout rl;
    myChips(View v)
    {
        rl = (RelativeLayout) v.getParent();
        slika = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_25);
        slika.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(dpToPx, dpToPx));

        rl.addView(slika);

    }
}
```

When I initilaze a new object from onClick method

```
 public void placeChip(View v)
{
   myChips test = new myChips(v);

}
```

I get a crash and an error on line

```
rl.addView(slika);
```

***"The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."***

I've tried some attemps but still can get rid of it.

Comment: Looking at the [Javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), the `findViewById` method looks for a **child** view with the given id. If this view has the given id, return this view. Have you done what the error says?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [findViewById()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)) mehtod:

> Look for a child view with the given id. If this view has the given
>   id, return this view.

That means your *slika* `ImageView` already has a parent, so you can add another parent to it.

This is why when you do `rl.addView(slika);`, it throws **IllegalStateException**.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first
```

Try this instead:

```
myChips(View v, Context context)
{
    rl = (RelativeLayout) v.getParent();
    slika = new ImageView(context);
    slika.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(dpToPx, dpToPx));

    rl.addView(slika);

}
```

And in your activity:

```
public void placeChip(View v)
{
   myChips test = new myChips(v, YourActivity.this);

}
```